# How to start Kotlin Coroutine in ViewModel with LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I was trying to get all launchable installed apps asynchronously from `ViewModel`.

This is my `ViewModel` class looks like:

```
class AppInstalledViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private var appInstalledLiveData: LiveData<ArrayList<AppInstalled>>? = null

    fun getAppInstalledLiveData(): LiveData<ArrayList<AppInstalled>> {
        if (appInstalledLiveData == null) {
            appInstalledLiveData = liveData {
                val appInstalled = ArrayList<AppInstalled>()
                val pm: PackageManager =
                    getApplication<Application>().applicationContext.packageManager

                val main = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)

                // Get launchable installed apps
                val launchAble = pm.queryIntentActivities(main, 0)

                // Sort the installed app list
                Collections.sort(launchAble, ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm))

                // Iterate over each launchable app and
                // add it to AppInstalled ArrayList
                for (l in launchAble) {
                    val activityInfo = l.activityInfo

                    activityInfo.run {
                        appInstalled.add(
                            AppInstalled(
                                loadLabel(pm).toString(),
                                applicationInfo.packageName,
                                loadIcon(pm)
                            )
                        )
                    }
                }

                emit(appInstalled)
            }
        }
        return appInstalledLiveData as LiveData<ArrayList<AppInstalled>>
    }
}
```

There is no problem with loading the app list. But, it seems that my code still not run asynchronously because it still freezes for a very few seconds before moving to the app installed list activity.

And this is the code I use to observe the `LiveData`:

```
appInstalledViewModel.getAppInstalledLiveData().observe(this, Observer { appInstalledItem ->
    if (appInstalledItem.size > 0) {
        appInstalledAdapter.appInstalled.addAll(appInstalledItem)
        app_list_progressbar.visibility = View.GONE
    }
})
```

I'm so confusing trying to use Kotlin on Android Development. This is my first time developing an app using Kotlin. I don't even know if the code I wrote above is a good code in the context of Kotlin's style.

Please help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of executing the long-running job in `Main` dispatcher. I highly recommend taking a look at [Coroutines Dispatchers](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/).

So, if you change the dispatcher to `Dispatchers.Default`, leading to fetch installed apps executing in a background thread, consequently, the UI will never be frozen.

```
appInstalledLiveData = liveData(Dispatchers.Default) {
    ...
}
```

---

**More:**

If you want to achieve a better structure, it could be even better not accessing the `LiveData` by calling a function:

```
class AppInstalledViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val reloadLiveData = MutableLiveData<Unit>()

    val installedAppsLiveData: LiveData<ArrayList<AppInstalled>> =
        reloadLiveData.switchMap {
            liveData(Dispatchers.Default) {
                emit(fetchInstalledApps())
            }
        }

    fun reloadApps() {
        reloadLiveData.postValue(Unit)
    }

    private fun fetchInstalledApps(): ArrayList<AppInstalled> {
        val appInstalled = ArrayList<AppInstalled>()
        val pm: PackageManager = getApplication<Application>().applicationContext.packageManager

        val main = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)

        // Get launchable installed apps
        val launchAble = pm.queryIntentActivities(main, 0)

        // Sort the installed app list
        Collections.sort(launchAble, ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm))

        // Iterate over each launchable app and
        // add it to AppInstalled ArrayList
        for (l in launchAble) {
            val activityInfo = l.activityInfo

            activityInfo.run {
                appInstalled.add(
                    AppInstalled(
                        loadLabel(pm).toString(),
                        applicationInfo.packageName,
                        loadIcon(pm)
                    )
                )
            }
        }
        return appInstalled
    }
}
```

Now, in the fragment:

```
appInstalledViewModel.installedAppsLiveData.observe(this, Observer { appInstalledItem ->
    if (appInstalledItem.size > 0) {
        appInstalledAdapter.appInstalled.addAll(appInstalledItem)
        app_list_progressbar.visibility = View.GONE
    }
})

appInstalledViewModel.reloadApps()
```

Using this structure, if you want to refresh the loaded data, it's just enough to call `appInstalledViewModel.reloadApps()`, then the list of apps gets updated.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. Finally, it doesn't freeze anymore. I thought every coroutines will use `Dispatchers.Default` by default. Thanks for the structure suggestion too :D. It helps me a lot.

Comment: You're welcome :) I hope the extended answer would be useful to you.

Comment: LiveData uses MAIN as default, the idea is that you'll move to another thread using `withContext()`